# Total number of comments of a post Facebook returns empty data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, comments

I am trying to get the total number of comments of a post using graph api

```
https://graph.facebook.com/post_id/comments?summary=true&limit=25&access_token=myaccesstoken
```

It has actually 2 comments but returns empty data set

```
{
   "data": [

   ],
   "summary": {
      "order": "chronological",
      "total_count": 0
   }
}
```

can anyone suggest me what is wrong

Comment: Maybe those comments are from users that have disabled all apps on Facebook - in which case their accounts and all content they create are completely invisible to any 3rd party app.

Comment: I have tested from another account, and its still showing blank result,